# How to see the URL of a source code of a website?

Tags: c#

I have a method that searches for movies in IMDB. Problem is, I only take into account if the site returns a page with movie OPTIONS. If the site automatically finds the movie in question, my program breaks.

Is there a way for me to check the URL of source code in C#?

Comment: I think perhaps some links to the different scenarios and more info in general would be good. This is a poorly asked question that has me reaching for the downvote. Have you actually written any code? Why not add some here?

Comment: What type of controls are you using, how are you searching for movies? Need more information to solve this I think

Comment: You mean your program works if the site returns a list of 'potential' movies based on your query, but it does not work if it returns the exact match?

Comment: Exactly wilpeck. Sorry if my question was a bit ambigous. My method waits for a list of sorts. But when an exact match is given and a direct link to the movie site, it crashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think maybe you're trying to parse the page instead of using a web service to access the information. parsing a page of dynamic content is difficult, if you want them, you must create a parser capable of handling such situations you describe.

You can try these links

- [Imdb Services](http://www.codeplex.com/imdb)
- [IMDB API](http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/)

Comment: +1 for the responder's suggestion to handle programmatically. -0.5 to the OP for asking a question about screen scraping in an operation that's somewhat questionable in terms of intent.

Answer (score 4):

[AllowAutoRedirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowautoredirect.aspx) = false;

Comment: Not exactly descriptive, but +1, because this is correct. You are redirected from the search page when there is only one result. You hit the search page and then the actual movie page. By not allowing the redirect to follow through, you'll remain on the search page - which won't have any information on it (since imdb wont even bother rendering it), but at least you'll know it happened...